# Access child member methods from function taking parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymer, member-functions

A test function needs to take in any object of a class that is derived from `Parent` and access the `Child` implementation of `Function()`. To me, this would seem like something easy to do. I tried to do the following. it feels intuitively right, but it does not work. It still calls the `Parent` implementation of `Function()`

```
Class Parent
{
Public:
    Parent();
    ~Parent();

    virtual void Function() = 0;

};

Class Child : public Parent
{
Public:
    Child();
    ~Child();
    void Function(){
        // Do something
    };
};

void Test(Parent Object)
{
    Object.Function();
};

int main()
{
    Child Object;
    Test(Child);
    return 0;
}
```

How would one implement such a thing?

Am I missing something small? or is this solution far off what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the real code.

Comment: `Parent.Function();` should be `object.Function();` and the same with the Child object. note that you are passing a copy of the Child object and it will be sliced. the polymorphic behavior can be demonstrated by pointers not by ordinary objects.

Comment: @G.M. what do you mean with the real code?

Comment: Sorry but have you tried to compile the code as shown.  It's important that the code you provide is, as I said, the *real* code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use virtual functions in C++ you must use a reference or a pointer. Try this

```
void Test(Parent& Object) // reference to Parent
{
    Object.Function();
};
```

You should research [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) to understand what goes wrong with your version, and why you must use a reference or a pointer.

Comment: A typo: `Object.Function()`